# Get Child Number From Elements WIth Same Class

Tags: jquery

I have HTML like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</uL>
```

Using jQuery, how would I get the number of the element clicked.  For instance, if two is clicked, I would want "2".  I'm hoping to do this without adding data elements etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use .index()

```
$('ul li').on('click',function(){
     alert($(this).index());
    });
```

As @Paul Roub said **.index()** start count from 0 so you should add + 1 to be **$(this).index() + 1**
See the demo [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln7qdL8x/1/)

Comment: You'll want `$(this).index() + 1`; `index()` counts from `0`.

Comment: @PaulRoub I know that man but I let the OP find it himself .. I just let him know the concept of how to get the index of element :) .. anyway you are right .. you can edit my answer and I will accept that :)